# Error only when I submit my package to CRAN

Tags: r, package, cran

I submitted my package [CDatanet](https://github.com/ahoundetoungan/CDatanet). Before that I checked (as CRAN) locally on Linux and I did not get any error. I only get a note about my address mail (which is normal).
However, when I submitted the package to CRAN, I got a warning and an error with the Window server.
https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/CDatanet_0.0.1_20210208_174258/Windows/00check.log

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ‐ (U+2010)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
* checking for detritus in the temp directory ... OK
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR, 1 WARNING, 1 NOTE
```

while the Debian server is ok.
https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/CDatanet_0.0.1_20210208_174258/Debian/00check.log

I also tried to check as CRAN locally on Window. But there was no error.

How can I fix this given that I am not able to reproduce the error locally?

Comment: A quick search on SE latex gives [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304939/package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u2010) which could be of relevance

Comment: Also all questions regarding problems in build should be send to the [R-pkg-devel](https://www.r-project.org/mail.html) mailing list. While not off-topic on SO, it is much more likely to get a useful answer on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @dario. I checked out that. But I am not able to call latex package in my .Rmd file right?

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. That is what I did 3 days ago but any feedback

Comment: Apologies, I must have missed the email. As for latex packages you can add them in the [header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211638/192957). One can even include full tex documents with written code that can be use in R-markdown. However, I am not sure how this affects packages pushed to cran. Maybe it would be simpler to search for the afflicted document and replace the specific unicode character.

Comment: Yes, you can call Latex packages from Rmd. But not sure what rules CRAN has in place for them. Either you remove the "offending" characters or you could try the code snipped suggested in the post i linked in the first comment... (i.e. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2010}{-}% support older LaTeX versions`)

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the manual and not in the vignettes. So I have any way to add latex package

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue using `tools::showNonASCIIfile()`.
By applying this function of each `.Rd` file, I got all non `UTF8` characters.